# ng-model to async xhr get/set field on my server

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm using Angular to create a preferences page.

Basically I have this field in a mysql table on my server, I want to ng-model my textbox to an async xhr request that sets it, and gets it.

Here is a jsfiddle I tried to put together to simulate it, without async though as I couldn't pull it off:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        {{prefs.delay}}
        Type a number: <input type="text" ng-model="prefs.delay"/>
</div>
```

And script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $q, $timeout) {

    var getPref = function(prefName) {
        /*
        var deferredMain_getPref = $q.defer();

        sendAsyncMessage(['getPref', prefName], function(aPrefVal) {
                deferredMain_getPref.resolve(aPrefVal);
        });
        */
        return prefStore[prefName]
    };


    $scope.prefs = {
        delay: getPref('delay')
    };

    $scope.$watch('prefs.delay', function(newValue) {
        sendAsyncMessage(['setPref', 'delay', newValue]);
    });


}

// check global pref store value with:
// content.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.wrappedJSObject.prefStore
// faking stuff below for demo
var prefStore = {
    delay: 100
};
function sendAsyncMessage(arrOfFuncNameAndArgs, aCallback) {
    if (arrOfFuncNameAndArgs[0] == 'setPref') {
        prefStore[arrOfFuncNameAndArgs[1]] = arrOfFuncNameAndArgs[2];
    } else if (arrOfFuncNameAndArgs[0] == 'getPref') {
        setTimeout(function() {
            aCallback(prefStore.delay);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Noitidart/c818h948/7/) - demo

In this fiddle I tried to fake the lag time for async behavior with `setTimeout` however failed, so removed the async behavior to show you the Angular works. How can i introduce a fake async with timeout?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do  ...

Comment: Thanks @sirrocco I'll clarify. Basically I have this field in a mysql table on my server, I want to ng-model my textbox to an xhr request that sets it, and gets it. I updated the question title and contents. I apreciate your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shot in the dark of *what I believe you are after*. First, `ng-pattern` will not prevent typing, only trigger validation. Instead, start out by using [input[number]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D). I'm *also guessing* you wish to see the manual value you set in your `<input />`, and not the keyed entry. For this, fire off `$event.preventDefault()`, bound to `ng-keydown`. Here is a complete working sample I wrapped in a decorator directive called `async`. Observe the following...

```
<input type="number" async ng-keydown="sync($event)" ng-model="model" />
```

---

```
.directive('async', ['myService', function(myService) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

            scope.sync = function($event) {
                $event.preventDefault();

                myService.getValue().then(function(response) {
                    myService.setValue(response).then(function(final) { 
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(final)
                        ngModel.$render();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Where `myService` is a mocked service leveraging `$q` and `$timeout`to emulate asynchronous behavior...

```
.factory('myService', ['$q', '$timeout', function($q, $timeout) {

    function getValue () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve(123);
        }, 250);

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function setValue(value) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve(value);
        }, 250);

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        getValue: getValue,
        setValue: setValue
    }
}]);
```

Where `123` - a sample value - is asynchronously daisy chained through the `getValue` and `setValue` functions. The result from `getValue` is also passed as a parameter to `setValue` in case further manipulation is needed before finally calling `ngModel.$setViewValue` and `ngModel.$render()`. Additionally, your objective is to likely leverage a request in `getValue()`. When getting to that point, simply inject a service such as `$http` and model accordingly...

```
function getValue () {
    return $http.get('/endpoint');
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwvmcpuz/) - working demo - type `1` => 500ms => `123`

---

If my assumption was wrong where you wished to prevent the keyed value initially, you can alternatively bind to `ng-change` and remove `$event.preventDefault`. If you chose this, you'll see your initial typed value, which will then change (get/set) as expected.