# Tie ng-model to async function for get and set

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asynchronous

I previously asked a question but my attempts at solving it made it very confusing, so here I'll present it without my attempts to solve it. (my old topic is here: [ng-model to async xhr get/set field on my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877820/ng-model-to-async-xhr-get-set-field-on-my-server) )

I am using angular in a browser addon. My goal is I have text box. I want to allow only numbers typed in it (which I accomplish with `ng-pattern="^\d+$/|/[^\s*]/"`). And I want to `ng-model` it to a function that asyncrhonously gets the value, and asynchronously sets the value.

These are the async set and get functions:

```
getBrowserPref('pref-name-here', function(aPrefValue) { })

setBrowserPref('pref-name-here', 'value-to-set-to');
```

I can't manage to pull this off in a simple way, is there any ideas out there? And in my solutions I have to do weird stuff like call `$scope.$digest`

Comment: Question is not clear without all relevant code and more specific problem description than `can't manage to pull this`

Comment: I'm not understanding the use of the word "ng-model" as a verb ("to ng-model it to a function"). `ng-model` gets/sets the model based on the textbox value. You can use `ng-change` to react to changes in the textbox (or you can $watch the bound model for changes) to do something, like start an async function. Is this what you want?

Comment: This feels a lot like an XY problem; both this question and the previous question lack a clear explanation of what the use case is here for this code, and both use incorrect terminology.  also, I wouldn't exactly say calling `$scope.$digest` is "doing weird stuff", though it's not necessary most of the time...

Comment: Thanks @NewDev I wanted whenever user changes box to send a `setPref`, and whenever page is loaded, or focused, it should do a `getPref`

Comment: @Noitidart, well, then do `ng-change="setPref()"` and in `getPref` set the model to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a bit tough to understand, so I have crafted a generic example that I hope can be molded into your working copy. This is a shot in the dark of *what I believe you are after*. Firstly, `ng-pattern` will not prevent typing, only trigger validation. Instead, start out by using [input[number]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D). I'm *also guessing* you wish to see the manual value you set in your `<input />`, and not the keyed entry. For this, fire off `$event.preventDefault()`, bound to `ng-keydown`. Here is a complete working sample I wrapped in a decorator directive called `async`. Observe the following...

```
<input type="number" async ng-keydown="sync($event)" ng-model="model" />
```

---

```
.directive('async', ['myService', function(myService) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

            scope.sync = function($event) {
                $event.preventDefault();

                myService.getValue().then(function(response) {
                    myService.setValue(response).then(function(final) { 
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(final)
                        ngModel.$render();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Where `myService` is a mocked service leveraging `$q` and `$timeout`to emulate asynchronous behavior...

```
.factory('myService', ['$q', '$timeout', function($q, $timeout) {

    function getValue () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve(123);
        }, 250);

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function setValue(value) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve(value);
        }, 250);

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        getValue: getValue,
        setValue: setValue
    }
}]);
```

Where `123` - a sample value - is asynchronously daisy chained through the `getValue` and `setValue` functions. The result from `getValue` is also passed as a parameter to `setValue` in case further manipulation is needed before finally calling `ngModel.$setViewValue` and `ngModel.$render()`. Additionally, your objective is to likely leverage a request in `getValue()`. When getting to that point, simply inject a service such as `$http` and model accordingly...

```
function getValue () {
    return $http.get('/endpoint');
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwvmcpuz/) - working demo - type `1` => 500ms => `123`

---

If my assumption was wrong where you wished to prevent the keyed value initially, you can alternatively bind to `ng-change` and remove `$event.preventDefault`. If you chose this, you'll see your initial typed value, which will then change (get/set) as expected.

Comment: Sincere thanks I'll give this a thorough look and let you know how I use it!

Comment: You are welcome! Share your findings when you can :)

Comment: Will definitely do, there's so much new stuff in here for me I will definitely have some findings and will for sure share :)